# Positioning button on the TableActivity from the code

Tags: java, android, button

I create table 3x3 with buttons.

```
for (int i = 0, lenI = field.length; i < lenI; i++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setWeightSum(1);
        for (int j = 0, lenJ = field[i].length; j < lenJ; j++) {
            Button button = new Button(this);
            buttons[i][j] = button;
            button.setOnClickListener(new Listener(i, j));
            row.addView(button, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            button.layout(Gravity.CENTER, Gravity.CENTER, Gravity.CENTER, Gravity.CENTER);
        }
        layout.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }
```

How can I place them on the center of the screen and set the width of 1/3 of the screen? Now buttons are at left side of activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While adding your buttons, use below code. Last parameter '1' is for weight.

```
row.addView(button, new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
```

Edit: [See docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html#TableRow.LayoutParams%28int,%20int,%20float%29)